# computing infimum of norm of Ax for unit vectors x

Tags: linear-algebra

How do we compute $\alpha=\inf\{\|Ax\|: \|x\|=1\}$ when $A$ is a matrix? If $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm, then $\alpha$ is the smallest singular value. If $\|x||$ is the 1-norm or $\infty$-norm, is there a process to compute $\alpha$?

Comment: It's probably not going to be anywhere near as nice, as the $1$-norm and the $\infty$-norm are not as coordinate independent as the $2$-norm. For instance, rotate the coordinate system $30^\circ$, and now try to describe the (old) $1$-norm.

Answer (score 0):

Since by the definition of the $\infty$-norm every vector with $||x||_{\infty}=1$ has an entry, which is 1, we should have

$inf\{max_{i} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{ik}x_k|\;|\;||x||_\infty=1\}=\\$
$inf\{max_{i} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{ik}x_k|\;|\;x=e_j\;for\;some\;j\in {1,...,n}\}=$

$min_j \{max_{i} |a_{ij}|\}$

I think.